# heroku cli not cannot execute any command

Tags: heroku

I have tried renaming my heroku app-name and followed: 
[heroku rename app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps)

I then remove and update my heroku git remote that came back with:

`Error: unable to get local issuer certificate`

and now none of heroku cli commands are working ie: login or create they all come back with the same  above^ error. To make thins work i cannot even execute any heroku cli commands on my other project that uses heroku

Has anyone ever face this error..?

Comment: The commands described in that page almost certainly didn't cause this. Did you do anything else?

Comment: Hey thank you for the replay, am am sure i did not. Could this be caused by some network issues...